# how to calculate row with condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How could I calculate how many in each category compare to the label?

```
      Credit  Term      Y
0  Excellent     3   safe
1       fair     5  risky
2       poor     3  risky
3       fair     5  risky
4  Excellent     5   safe
5       poor     3  risky
6  Excellent     5   safe
7       poor     3  risky
8       fair     3   safe
9       fair     5   safe
```

this is my data and I want to calculate how many safe excellent poor and fair and also how many risky excellent poor and fair like excellent 3 safe 0 risky so on
I calculate:

```
data[(data['Credit']=='Excellent')&(data['Y']=='safe')].count()
data[(data['Credit']=='Excellent')&(data['Y']=='risky')].count()
```

or

```
elements,counts = np.unique(data['Credit'],return_counts = True)
```

How could I make a table like

```
               safe    risky
excellent      3        0
poor           0        3
fair           2        2
```

Comment: This probably needs a `numpy` tag.

Comment: It's Pandas mostly.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas `groupby()` and `unstack()`:

```
data.groupby(['Credit', 'Y']).count().unstack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot_table: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
      credit  term      Y
0  Excellent     3   safe
1       fair     5  risky
2       poor     3  risky
3  Excellent     5   safe
4       fair     5   safe

In [17]: pd.pivot_table(df, index=['credit'], columns=['Y'], aggfunc='count')
Out[17]:
           term
Y         risky safe
credit
Excellent   NaN  2.0
fair        1.0  1.0
poor        1.0  NaN

In [18]: pd.pivot_table(df, index=['credit'], columns=['Y'], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
Out[18]:
           term
Y         risky safe
credit
Excellent     0    2
fair          1    1
poor          1    0
```

Comment: Thank you. How could I index it? my final goal is to calculate entropy with each row so that will be the weighted entropy